# Will a thread waiting for a HTTP response hog the CPU?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, http, wait

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

When running the above code there is a pause when `request.GetResponse()` is called. We are waiting for a response to our HTTP request.

What I would like to know is whether this thread will go to sleep, allowing another thread to use the CPU, or just hog the CPU and 'busy wait' while waiting for the HTTP response.

If `request.GetResponse()` does cause busy waiting what can I do to make this code make more efficient use of the CPU?

Comment: `I would like to know is whether this thread will go to sleep` Yes.

Comment: Yes the thread will go sleep and not consume any CPUs, but if instead of GetResponse you use GetResponseAsync, this thread can be resued for other purpose till we get a response. Of course you be required to implement Async/ Await from top to bottom.

Comment: Your default assumption should be that functions provided by the platform you're developing on are well-designed and do what they're documented to do in an efficient manner. If there were a platform that didn't justify this level of trust, you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the thread will 'go to sleep', the operating system will ensure that. Once the I/O operation is done, OS will wake up the thread.